# How to get intellij idea to recognise methods generated by my annotation processor

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, abstract-syntax-tree, annotation-processing

I have created a multi module project namely **App** and **Mods**, **App** contains the main method and **Mods** contains the annotation and its annotation processor.
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CRMt.png)

I have used the annotation on a class defined in the **App** module called *Test*, and further created an instance of it in the main method and also called the the *getTest* method that gets generated by the annotation processor.
[Test class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMNFO.png)
[Main method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9M6N.png)

The problem I am facing is that the method is not recognised by intellij and shows an error, but the project compiles and runs just fine.
[Run results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np3eJ.png)

How do I get intellij idea to recognise methods generated by a custom annotation processor?

#Note: annotation processor uses AST modification to generate the method

[Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIyDu.png)
[Annotation processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRWes.png)

Comment: Have you enabled annotation processing? See [IntelliJ doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotation-processors-support.html)

Comment: If yes, please share your project sample at https://uploads.jetbrains.com and share the UploadID here to check the configuration

Comment: I am not sure if these are the correct settings, but I have turned enabled annotation processing for the profiles Maven default annotation processors profile & Annotation profile for AstTest but not for the Default profile. I have added the screen shot of it in the main question at the end.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov here is the sample project Upload id: 2023_05_15_V3pSsNMD2m4eQvcWjGw2FK (file: AstTest.zip)

Answer (score 0):

IDEA does recognize Classes and Methods generated by APs, but it expects them to be located in `target/generated-sources`.
In the Project you have provided you seem to be using an approach that is closer to what [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) is doing.

Unfortunately, recognizing Classes/Methods generated in such a way would require a custom support in editor for each individual implementation.